# ADP API cannot get past SSL error

Tags: php, api, ssl, xampp

I have an ADP SSL key, pem, pfx, csr.  I'm attempting to connect from my local machine using a Xampp server.

For the life of me, I cannot get past this error:
"unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)".

I was able to get Google Postman working with the ADP API by installing the .pfx file in the MS Management Console.

Do I need to install these files somewhere in the Xampp server itself?

I have a folder in the app that stores the .key and .pem file that I'm pointing to.

Any insight is appreciated.

```
$auth = array();
$auth['cert'] = "/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem";
$auth['key'] = "/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.key";
$auth['user'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$postfields = array(
   "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token",
   CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $auth['cert'],
   CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $auth['key'],
   CURLOPT_USERPWD => $auth['user'],
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postfields, '', '&')
));

$auth['token'] = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($auth['token'], true);


$_SESSION['bearer'] = $response['access_token'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

   CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.adp.com/hr/v1/corporate-contacts' ,
   CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $auth['cert'],
   CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $auth['key'],
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
   'Accept: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth['token']
)

));
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$data)
    print_r('ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch));
else
    print_r('SUCCESS: ' . curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

> .. I cannot get past this error: "unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)".

I have no knowledge of the ADP API but the error message suggests that either the keys is not found (which you claim it is there), does not have the correct permissions (is it readable by the web server?), does not have the correct format (should start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` etc) or that you have a passphrase for this key and you have given the wrong one or none. Looking at the code I see that you provide cert and key but no passphrase:

```
CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $auth['cert'],
CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $auth['key'],
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $auth['user'],
```

I don't know if you try to wrongly use CURLOPT_USERPWD to give the passphrase if the passphrase is completely missing, but to add you would need to use [CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There is no passphrase.  Key file indeed does begin with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.  File permissions look fine - It's my Windows machine running Xampp.

Comment: This key and cert was given to me by a co-worker who created them on his machine.  Should this matter?

Comment: @bacemail: as long as the key matches the cert it should not matter.  On how to check that this pair belongs together see https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/684/17/how-do-i-verify-that-a-private-key-matches-a-certificate-openssl

Comment: Key matches the cert.  Thanks for all the advice.  I will continue to troubleshoot and post my solution when I find it.

Comment: My path to my cert was not correct.  Added __DIR__ to the beginning of the path.  Now the script is finding my certs.  Thank you so much for the troubleshooting help!

Answer (score 0):

After all that troubleshooting, I find that the paths to the .pem and .key files were not correct.

Correct syntax:
    $auth['cert'] = **DIR** . "/certs/my_cert.pem";
    $auth['cert'] = **DIR** . "/certs/my_cert.key";

Working now (lost some brain cells).

Comment: Were you able to post this api on adp market place ?